How to create a plot tree object with different actions without inheriting (e.g. simple ScriptableObject)?
I need to create a game event with different actions like in Slay the Spire game (see a photo below).

The object must contain a list of actions (e.g. give some item to player or else). On choosing some action the event can continue so you will have: new specific text for this choise, new buttons with actions.
The problem is to make a folded structure of texts and actions (actions are the most hard part) without using ridiculous amount of classes for each folded event.
However the straight forward solution is to write a class for each event:
public class PlotRoom : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializedField] private Text textField;

    // Imagine some object that can create buttons by actions
    [SerializedField] private ButtonsContainer buttons;

    [SerializedField] private List<string> texts; // Same length as actionGroups
    private abstract List<List<Action>> actionGroups { get; }

    protected void Quit() { //quit the  plot }

    protected void UpdatePlot(int group)
    {
        textField.text = texts[group];
        buttons.Spawn(actionGroups[group])
    }
}

public class Plot1 : PlotRoom
{
    protected override List<List<Action>> actionGroups => new() 
    {
        new () { SomeAction1, SomeAction2, Quit },
        new () { SomeAction2, Quit }
    }

    private void SomeAction1()
    {
        DoSomething();
        UpdatePlot(1);
    }

    private void SomeAction2()
    {
        DoSomethigElse();
        Quit();
    }
}

public class Plot2 : PlotRoom
{
    // ...
}

Is there some another way to create such groups without creating a lot of classes? Or is there a way to upgrade existing solution?
